# D3.js - Use newline character in rendered text

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I wish to use newline characters for the node text in the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/0vbtvoon/22/

I would like the text to have a new line for each word. For example, 'Joe Bloggs' would become 'Joe \nBloggs' where \n is the line break.

The problem lies on line 184 of the javascript with:

```
nodes.append("text")
        .text(function (d) {
        return d.name;
    })
```

I cannot work out how to cause a line break for node text. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: SVG has no native support for line breaks. I don't know, if d3 has any built in functionality to cope with that. If not, build something yourself using either  `<tspan>` or `<foreignObject>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will have to write a function to manually break out the text into separate lines. Mike Bostock has a nice [function written already though](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321):

```
function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm now using that function and from line 184 the code now reads `nodes.append("text")
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.name;
})
.selectAll("text")
      .call(wrap, x.rangeBand())
    .attr("x", tx)
    .attr("y", ty);` Unfortunately all the node text is now in the top left corner of the svg. Do you have an idea of what I've done wrong?

Comment: Could you check if `.style("text-anchor", "middle")` helps center the text?

Comment: Sadly not! I have a jsfiddle located here that shows what's going wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/ft5107wo/

Comment: I see the issue - it wasn't finding a `dy` attribute for the text and it makes more sense to pass in the width of the node for something like this. I edited both the wrap function and the text construction. I updated your jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ft5107wo/2/ :)